# msvcprt and crt

Tags: c++

I have editbin msvcprt and look for scanf for instance but i can't find it.

Does it mean crt is not encapsulate in msvcprt ?
Does it mean cin function doesn't use scanf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two libraries:  the C Run-Time library (called the "CRT") and the Standard C++ Library.  The `scanf` function is a part of the CRT, not the Standard C++ Library.

Both the CRT and the Standard C++ Library are linked in automatically when you compile a C++ program.  You can read the details about which libraries get linked in when on the [C Run-Time Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

In this specific case, the corresponding CRT library for the msvcprt.lib version of the Standard C++ Library (`/MD` / Multithreaded DLL) is msvcrt.lib.

Comment: Why the CRT is linked in when you build a Cpp soft ? what the need to this ? what there is in CRT that it is not in Standard C++ library ?

Comment: Tell me, what is "a Cpp soft"? You keep talking about that.

Comment: @Guillaume07:  With Visual C++, both C and C++ programs utilize the CRT.  The Standard C++ Library builds on top of and utilizes the CRT.

Comment: @sehe: sorry, Cpp soft = Software developped in C++

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool *and* the wrong file.  Use dumpbin.exe and msvcrt.lib